# How to begin, rollback, commit a transaction in Xcode with sqlite

Tags: objective-c, ios, transactions, sqlite

I want to create some methods to begin, commit or rollback a transaction in Xcode.

I want to know which methods of sqlite3 library I have to use.

Is it OK to use sqlite3_prepare_v2?
Or sqlite3_readonly_stmt?

Comment: what platform? what language? You should replace the Xcode tag with a useful one. Xcode is just an IDE. If your question is not about extending Xcode so it can use sqlite transactions you should not use the Xcode tag.

Comment: @Curlyman - it is not OBVIOUS. You can use many different languages in XCode and on the iPhone.

Comment: Yes, u can. u can do many things. Just if is not specified is obvious is objective-c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by executing the following self-explanatory commands in SQLite: `begin immediate transaction`, `commit transaction` and `rollback transaction`.

Note: I've used the `immediate` transaction behavior. For information about it and the other ones (`deferred`, `exclusive`), take a look [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html).

To execute the command in Objective-C, use this (where `sql` contains one of the above commands as an `NSString`; and `db` is your database handle - `sqlite3*`):

```
if (sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
  // deal with error...
}
```